# When should the Controller get instantiated?

Tags: php, oop, model-view-controller

I am building an AJAX web app, using PHP for my back end. I am trying to design a routing system that will let me easily drop new pages in, and let me focus on the Javascript. The actual pages that PHP will be serving up are simple, just views that are essentially containers for Javascript charts (built with [d3.js](http://d3js.org/)). Thus, my controller won't even have to interact with my model until I start making AJAX calls.

I am new to OOP, especially in back end. I've been doing a bit with Javascript, but I am brand new to incorporating OOP with MVC & solving the issue of routing. I know there are modules/plugins out there that have Routing classes written, but as the back end part of this project is very straight-forward - essentially, how best to serve up an 'About' page on a blog - I'd like to take this opportunity to learn it thoroughly myself.

I have one controller:

```
<?php
//controller.php
include 'views/view.php';

class Controller
{

    public function homeAction() {
        $view = new View();
        $view->setTemplate('views/home.php');
        $view->render();
    }

    public function categoryAction($category) {
        $view = new View();
        $view->setTemplate("views/Monitor/{$category}/{$category}.php");
        $view->setCategory($category);
        $view->render();
    }

    public function monitorAction($category, $monitor) {
        $view = new View();
        $view->setTemplate("views/Monitor/{$category}/{$monitor}.php");
        $view->setCategory($category);
        $view->setMonitor($monitor);
        $view->render();
    }

}

?>
```

Right now, I instantiate my controller at the beginning of `index.php`:

```
<?php
// Load libraries
require_once 'model.php';
require_once 'controller.php';

$controller = new Controller();

$uri = str_replace('?'.$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

// home action
if ($uri == '/') {
  $controller->homeAction();

// /{category}/{monitor}
} elseif (preg_match("#/(.+)/(.+)#", $uri, $matches) ) {
  $category = $matches[1];
  $monitor  = $matches[2];
  $controller->monitorAction($category, $monitor);

// /{category}
} elseif (preg_match("#/([^/.]+)#", $uri, $matches) ) {
  $category = $matches[1];
  $controller->categoryAction($category);

// 404  
} else {
    header('Status: 404 Not Found');
    echo '<html><body><h1>Page Not Found</h1></body></html>';
}



if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && (!empty($_GET)) && $_GET['action'] == 'get_data') {

    $function = $_GET['chart'] . "_data";
    $dataJSON = call_user_func($function);
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo $dataJSON;

}

?>
```

I have read a bit about PHP's autoloader, but I'd like to get it down manually first, because I want to make sure and understand the fundamentals.

Is this the appropriate place to instantiate my `Controller` object?

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more of the problem? What kind of application it is?

Answer (score 1):

First, your architecture is facing some major problems. You need a router to take care of your requested URIs by the users and next you need an initialization state for your system. The usual way to create `Controller`s is to `extend` a parent class, then in your parent class `__construct` method you can initialize your children controllers, however, your system isn't in a good shape.

This is a gold link that I never delete:

http://johnsquibb.com/tutorials/mvc-framework-in-1-hour-part-one

Comment: Unfortunately your "gold link" contains really terrible practices and suggestions. Also, there is no MVC in it. Only another Rails-like mess.

Comment: I would love some guidance here. I seem unable to find a definitive source of info on this stuff.

Comment: @tereško, this article is quite old but there are good practices about getting a MVC project done. The controller part is a well explained part and for a beginner, it has really some good stuffs. Of course the modern MVC is very different than the old ones, but here is the matter of learning something.

Comment: heh .. controller part is one of the most wrong. That article recommend dumping both application and UI logic in said controller, which completely violates the basic concepts of MVC. You basically end up with "controller-that-does-everything" + glorified ORM + dumb templates. That is not MVC.

Comment: @tereško, you're right about this. There is no loading of views, using models as templates, and many other gaps, but at least there is an example about writing a controller. And I didn't say follow this article to create a MVC system!